# Fast way (hot key) to move a window from one screen to another (working on two screens) on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Is there a fast way to move a window from one screen to another when I use an external screen on my laptop? A hot hey of some sort would be optimal.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>-></kbd>(right arrow)

Or

<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd><-</kbd>(left arrow)

Will move windows between screens on a multi monitor setup.